# how to rotate a sub-matrix NxN by 90 degree clockwise in a bigger AxB matrix - in Java

Tags: java, matrix

everyone ! I'm trying to rotate sub-matrix NxN for 90 degree clockwise within a bigger AxB matrix. Most answers I found is only dealt with a whole matrix NxN. Below is the example.

Given a A x B matrix rotate a sub-matrix NxN for 90 degree clockwise.

Sample input given [3 x 4] matrix rotate sub-matrix [3 x 3] for 90 degree clockwise.

```
 0  [1  2  3 ]  4
 5  [6  7  8 ]  9
 10 [11 12 13] 14
```

Expected output

```
 0  [11  6  1]  4
 5  [12  7  2]  9
 10 [13  8  3] 14
```

Really appreciate if someone can help me out. Thanks !

Comment: Did you try the examples for whole matrices and adjusting the indices? An easy way to deal with this would be to copy the NxN submatrix to an NxX matrix, rotate it and copy the result back. Doing it inplace might be more efficient but the copy-rotate-copy approach might be easier to start with.

Comment: I can rotate the sub-matrix 90 degree clockwise , if it is left alignment . But since, it is middle alignment or right alignment. I haven't figured it out how to rotate it yet.

Comment: As I said, an easy way would be to copy the sub matrix so you have a "standalone" matrix. Since you know how to rotate that you're almost done here - just rotate the "standalone" matrix then copy the rotated values back.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`top` and `left` are the coordinates of the upper left corner of the submatrix.
`n` is the size of the submatrix.

```
static int[][] rotate(int[][] a, int top, int left, int n) {
    int height = a.length, width = a[0].length;
    int[][] b = new int[height][];
    for (int x = 0; x < height; ++x)
        b[x] = Arrays.copyOf(a[x], width);
    for (int x = top, xmax = top + n, ty = left + n - 1; x < xmax; ++x, --ty)
        for (int y = left, ymax = left + n, tx = 0; y < ymax; ++y, ++tx)
            b[tx][ty] = a[x][y];
    return b;
}
```

And

```
int[][] a = {
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
    {10, 11, 12, 13, 14},
};
int[][] b = rotate(a, 0, 1, 3);
for (int[] row : b)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

output:

```
[0, 11, 6, 1, 4]
[5, 12, 7, 2, 9]
[10, 13, 8, 3, 14]
```

Comment: Side note: I'd highly recommend using curly braces for code blocks such as if-statements or loops even if they only contain one statement. That way you don't rely on intendation etc. to spot those blocks and a lot of harm can come from inserting code and unintentionally pushing statements out of the block (e.g. Apple had a huge security hole due to this a couple of years ago).